# String to System.Windows.Input.Key

Tags: c#

I need a function that takes a String as an argument, and returns a System.Windows.Input.Key. E.G:

```
var x = StringToKey("enter"); // Returns Key.Enter
var y = StringToKey("a"); // Returns Key.A
```

Is there any way to do this other than if/else's or switch statements?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at [KeyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.aspx), it can convert a `Key` to and from a `string`.

```
KeyConverter k = new KeyConverter();
Key mykey = (Key)k.ConvertFromString("Enter");
if (mykey == Key.Enter)
{
    Text = "Enter Key Found";
}
```

Comment: This should be the more safer/flexible option.

Comment: I haven't known about `KeysConverter` before! Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` != `System.Windows.Input.Key`.

Comment: @Etienne: I believe BugFinder might have been thinking of the Forms version as he wrote the answer, but the WPF version is still available.  I went ahead and adjusted the example to fit that.

Answer (score 9):

Key is an enum, so you can parse it like any enum:

```
string str = /* name of the key */;
Key key;
if(Enum.TryParse(str, true, out key))
{
    // use key
}
else
{
    // str is not a valid key
}
```

Keep in mind that the string has to match exactly (well, almost; it's a case insensitive comparison because of that `true` parameter) the name of the enumeration value.

Answer (score 3):

```
var key = Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), "Enter");
```

Case-insensitive option:

```
var key = Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), "enter", true);
```

Comment: For case insensitive, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx

Comment: @Etienne de Martel - thank you. I didn't know about the overload. Edited the answer.